# Conflicting memory ranges on Windows 98 SE for video card

Tags: windows, video, amd-graphics-card

My card is a ATI Radeon 9550 and my computer is a Dell Dimension 4600 with a 2.4 Ghz Pentium 4. I have seen forum posts about this before but they just say “that computer is not designed for Win 98” but I am more interested in why I get memory and i/o conflicts causing my video driver not to work.

I have also tried the GeForce MX2 that came in this computer with the same results.

[image]

Comment: I have edited in your picture but you should also describe *in text* what the picture shows: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

This is going way, way back but it appears as though the computer isn't truly plug-n-play compliant. That might be what they mean by "doesn't support Windows 98". There should be some settings in the BIOS of the computer that will let you reserve blocks at C0000-CCFFF for non-plug-n-play devices. You will have to play with it.

Comment: This computer is from 2003 so it’s more XP era so it should be plug and play compliant. Also the bios is very simplistic, not much to change.

Comment: You are at the mercy of the BIOS. See if there is an option to turn off ACPI (Plug-n-Play) then save and go back in. More options should show up.at that point.